# Secure way to check if a user is authorized to visit a page and redirect others Facebook login

Tags: javascript, html, database, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

If i have a page which only authorized users can get in, what is the most secure way to check that, and most important how to redirect people who isn't to other page in a secure way?

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
         // do nothing its ok..
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        window.location.replace("/login.php");
        } else {
      window.location.replace("/login.php");
        }
      });
```

i guess this way is not secure, so please help me get a better way of securly checking if a person is authorized to be in a particular page

Answer (score 0):

Some more information about your environment would be helpful, but in general, and going off the assumption your back-end is built on PHP based on the redirect pages in your snippet, you are correct in saying that it is not secure.

The key problem which needs to be addressed here is that the user has access to the client-side scripts, javascript in most cases.  If you are trying to prevent any access to a given page, you need to handle it server-side.  The methodology for this will vary with the authentication mechanisms/libraries involved.

If you want to prevent someone from accessing any code that would execute on the page:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['some_value']){
    $authorised = ($_SESSION['some_value'] === $correct) ? true : false;
    if($authorised){
        header('Location: /logged_in/');
        exit(0); // or do anything else needed
    }else{
        header('Location: /not_logged_in/');
        exit(1); // no further code will execute
    }
}
```

The clear difference is this is evaluated *server-side*, but care must be taken to ensure that the only way to obtain 'some_value' legitimately is also done server-side. This is a very general example that would be better expanded into a class for more robust authentication, more modularity, etc.  If you are using third-party application (Oauth for example), you must make sure you have configured this correctly server-side as well of course.

In short, your authentication will vary with the libraries and environment you are using, but what is common across the different possible implementations is a distrust of arbitrary user input.  There is not a secure way to implicitly trust a user to be honest.

To give an answer more specific to *your* use-case, more details are necessary in regard to your environment, requirements, what libraries are available to you, etc.

Comment: I agree with everything you wrote but i think the core of my question is how do i get this "some_value" and put it in the php file in a secure way, considering this "some value" is coming from a javascript code. i dont want to use php to get this value, this value can achive only in a javascript code

Comment: Logically, you are asking: How can I get a non-secure script-generated value to a secure location on the server?
Store the value outside the document root, where the php system user (`www-data`?, still no additional environmental information) can access it, but an end-user cannot.
However, if they are logging into *your* site, this information is likely in a database.  If you are using google, etc to authenticate, you should probably look here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
for an overview.
It would also be helpful to know why this js-only requirement exists.

Comment: do you think that this is a secure way?    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
         window.location.replace("/login.php?id="getAccessToken()); ||||||||||||||||||||||||||| and then on the php page checking the valid of the token?

Comment: Provided FB.getLoginStatus is trusted, the only way a user should be able to access your page is if they have said account.  In that sense you can trust it in the same way you trust a session id.  I will not say it is secure since I do not know what level of access this grants/how it is used/etc, but for determining whether someone has a trusted login on another site(establishing identity) yes that can be used.  Other access-level controls accessible from the 3rd party API can also have the same assurance.